# asp.net core 3.1 unauthorized 401 redirect to an unauthorized razorpage not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am new to .net core but have developed in asp.net for a few years. I have a site in core that is Windows AD based auth. I am using AD groups to control access, my razor index page is setup for an AD group

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ADRoleOnly")]
```

when a user that is not part of the group tries to access the razor index page they get a 403 denied. I am trying to figure out how to redirect them to a razor page i have setup as "/unAuthAccess"  . This "/unAuthAccess" razorpage is set to

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

and i verified that users in the AD group can view this '/unAuthAccess" page fine, as well as users that are not part of the AD group that get the 403, so the allowanonymous is working for the /unAuthAccess page.

so i don't know where or HOW to put in a redirect when any users hits any page i have set with the policy when they don't have authorization to view it.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ADRoleOnly")]
```

I have tried in Startup.cs the following with both 401 and 403 status

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
         app.Use(async (context, next) =>
         {
               context.Request.Path = "/UnAuthAccess";
               await next();
         });
    }
 });
```

which did not work. so then i tried

```
 app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Errors/{0}");
```

with the razor page set to "/Errors/401" and also "/Errors/403" i couldn't remember which one it should be set to and catch the unAuth access from the user.

either way the user doesn't get redirected to my razorpage and i just get a standard browser HTTP error 403 denied message.

just looking for help on how redirects work in core??? should i be doing the redirect somehow directly from the razor page cs/backend code if so how??

I have this working in old asp.net 4.x using Global.asax, but this method does not work in core :(

```
if (Response.StatusCode == 401 && Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/unauthAccess.aspx");
            }
```

Comment: When you use `app.UseStatusCodePages`, have you debug to see the value of `Response.StatusCode` when the user is unauthorized?

Comment: so debugging ,  i set a stop in Startup.cs on the line "if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 401" and it never gets hit , and then it just goes straight to the 403 error in browser

Comment: @mj1313 you post made me sit and just start my thought process over :) so thanks

Answer (score 2):

i figured it out , i had to move the line

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("Errors/{0}");
```

to before staticfiles and routing calls in Startup.cs

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //sets ad domain and mail server for specific test environments
                misc.ad_domain = "corp.emc.com";
                misc.smtp_server = "mailhub.lss.emc.com";

                app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Errors/{0}");

                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Errors/{0}");

                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();       
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
```

yes i know i just put it in env.IsDevelopment for my debug testing. I hope this helps anyone else moving into asp.net core from previous .net i know it was a learning curve for me on where stuff gets placed in Startup.cs

with this setup i had to change my razor page route from "/unAuthAccess" to "Errors/401", to get my unauth page to display :)