# Customize Asp.NET Core Identity Unauthorized Response Type and Statuscode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got a WebApi endpoint with an `[Authorized]` attribute. I did not configure any additional policies or anything.

```
[Authorized]
[Route("foo")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(FooModel model) 
{ 
    // .......
}
```

When I try to hit this endpoint and I'm not authenticated I'll get a 404 response w/o content.

What I want to get: A customized response type with a 401 statuscode. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814217/asp-net-core-3-1-unauthorized-401-redirect-to-an-unauthorized-razorpage-not-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add following code in your `Startup` Class:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

Your action:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(FooModel model) 
{ 
// ...
}
```

By the way,this will cause you can't redirect to your Login page, you can set it only works for `api`, like the following:

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api")
                    && context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
                {
                    context.Response.Clear();
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
                context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

Comment: If it doesn't work,please share your `startup` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[Route]` to make sure you are calling the function correctly

```
[Authorized]
[Route("Foo")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(FooModel model) 
{ 

}
```